# How to "autofill" your dataframe after calling the groupby function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to create a dataframe which gives me the average price of listings per neighbourhood, per year, per month. I created this dataframe in Python but it's not entirely what I want

```py
agg_dict = {"price": np.mean}
dfGrouped = df.groupby(["neighbourhood_group", "Year", "Month"]).agg(agg_dict)
```

This gives me the following dataframe after calling head().

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB5Qo.jpg

This is almost what I want. However I want the rows to be "autofilled" like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzIdu.jpg

Comment: Try reset index using `dfGrouped.reset_index()`.

Comment: This answer did the trick, thank you!

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your apparently "missing" data are actually in place, but they are **not displayed**.

The default standard of displaying MutliIndex is that "repeating" values
are just hidden.

To override this behaviour, run:

```
pd.options.display.multi_sparse = False
```

and display your DataFrame again.

But if you want to change the display standard only for
a **single** printout, run:

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print(<your_DataFrame>)
```

Comment: The first option gave me the answer. The only problem I had was that I still couldn't select a column. For example dfGrouped['Month'] gave me a 'KeyError'. Using dfGrouped.reset_index() solved this.